# vertical listview android application?

Tags: android, listview

i am making a weather application and i want to display its details in a listview and i am having problems it is giving me errors i dont understand i have been trying to fix it and i cant think of any other way .please i need help i hope i explained the question well

this is my error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.helloworldng.bip/com.helloworldng.bip.navigate.Search}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.helloworldng.bip.navigate.Search has no zero argument constructor
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.helloworldng.bip.navigate.Search has no zero argument constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1597)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1595)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

this is the first class

```
package com.helloworldng.bip.navigate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.helloworldng.bip.GetTrafficReportTask;
import com.helloworldng.bip.R;
import com.helloworldng.bip.data.BIPContract;


public class Search extends ListActivity {

    private final String LOG_TAG = GetTrafficReportTask.class.getSimpleName();


    public static  final String BIP_STATE = "state";
    public static  final String BIP_CITY = "city";
    public static  final String BIP_DESC = "description";
    public static  final String BIP_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://www.helloworldng.com/bip/get_traffic.php";
    private final Context mContext;

    //public FetchWeatherTask(Context context, ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter) {
    public Search(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        //mForecastAdapter = forecastAdapter;
    }

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.droptrafic);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(null);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);
    }

    private void getTrafficDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
            throws JSONException {

        try {
            JSONArray trafficArray = new JSONArray(forecastJsonStr);
            //JSONArray trafficArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(BIP_TRAFFIC);

            // Insert the new weather information into the database
            Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(trafficArray.length());

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            dayTime = new Time();

            for (int i = 0; i < trafficArray.length(); i++) {
                String state;
                String status;
                JSONObject dayTraffic = trafficArray.getJSONObject(i);

                state = dayTraffic.getString(BIP_STATE);
                status = dayTraffic.getString(BIP_STATUS);

                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) dayTraffic,
                        R.layout.single_drop, new String[] { state,status
                }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.desc});

                setListAdapter(adapter);
                ListView lv = getListView();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return null;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String locationQuery = params[0];

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;
        String app_id = "b7940b102bb44bb3c5accd21eb44da00";


        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://www.helloworldng.com/bip/get_traffic.php";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String APPID = "appid";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL);

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            Log.e("Today Traffic", url.toString());
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG + " Manual", forecastJsonStr);
            getTrafficDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
            // to parse it.
            // return null;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

this is the listview xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the first xml class single_drop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Heavy Traffic"
        android:id="@+id/status" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="state"
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What caused the error? What did you do last?

Comment: Try removing the activity constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call super(context) in your activity constructor.

Comment: where in the code do i place it am a little suprised

Comment: In your search activity constructor.

Comment: i removes the    public Search(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        //mForecastAdapter = forecastAdapter;
    }
codeed in the search.java class it hass stoped giving me error but it comes up and does not display anything

Comment: Your listview id is not correct. Should be @android:id/list. Since you are using ListActivity.

Comment: Then you create an adapter for each array element in your JsonArray. You should only have one adapter after your for loop....

Comment: And by the way, the question was Why do you get does errors. This is the right answer for that, you should probably open another question(s).